# How to optimise a query with inner join and order by

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, index, optimization

I'm struggling with optimising my query. I've tried to solve the issue with various indexes by none of them seems to be helpful.

There are 3 tables: `transfers(id, amount, type, timestamp, file_id)`, `files(id, path)`, `file_to_report(id, report_id, file_id)`.

`transfers` and `files` have many to one relation.
`files` and `file_to_report` have many to many relation.

1 report ≈ 20k files ≈ 200k transfers

I have to select all transfers of particular type for particular report_id, sorted by timestamp.

```
SELECT t.id, t.amount, t.timestamp
FROM transfers t
INNER JOIN file_to_report ftr ON t.file_id = ftr.file_id
WHERE t.type = 'debit'
  AND ftr.report_id = 1
ORDER BY t.timestamp, t.id
OFFSET 5000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Currently this query takes ~20s. With every next page it needs more and more time. Without `ORDER BY` it takes 0.05s.

I've tried to create the next indexes to avoid sorting / make filtering by `file_to_report` faster:

```
CREATE INDEX i1 ON transfer (timestamp, id);
CREATE INDEX i2 ON transfer (timestamp, id, file_id);
CREATE INDEX i3 ON transfer (file_id, timestamp, id);
CREATE INDEX i4 ON transfer (type, timestamp, id);
CREATE INDEX i5 ON transfer (type);
CREATE INDEX i6 ON transfer (type, file_id, timestamp, id);

CREATE index i7 ON file_to_report (file_id);
CREATE index i8 ON file_to_report (file_id, report_id);
```

However, none of these indexes makes the query faster. Please, help me to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Can you add the actual queryplans by using pastetheplan.com

Comment: Try adding an included column to i4: `CREATE INDEX i4 ON transfer (type, timestamp, id) INCLUDE(file_id);`

Answer (score 1):

### almost

You'd want to adjust this index to include `amount`:

`CREATE INDEX i6 ON transfer (type, file_id, timestamp, id) INCLUDE (amount);`

And change this index to switch the column order:

```
CREATE index i8 ON file_to_report (report_id, file_id);
```

### local test

Using a similar query against tables I can access:

```
SELECT
    u.Id,
    u.CreationDate,
    u.Reputation
FROM dbo.Users AS u
JOIN dbo.Posts AS p
  ON u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
WHERE u.DownVotes = 0
AND   p.PostTypeId = 1
ORDER BY
    u.CreationDate,
    u.Id
OFFSET 5000 ROW
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROW ONLY;
```

With the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX u
ON dbo.Users
(DownVotes, Id, CreationDate)
INCLUDE(Reputation);

CREATE INDEX p
ON dbo.Posts
(PostTypeId, OwnerUserId);
```

I get the following query plan, completing in 169ms:

[image: NUTS]